# Ubuntu 15.10 And Samba share

Tags: 15.10, samba, mate, caja

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 with mate, I am connected to my home network, but it seems like it's not possible to access Samba shared drive on the network.

I correctly see the network resources but when I try to mount a disk with caja, after a while I get an error message saying "Not-possible to access the disk"

Can someone help me?

Comment: is that the exact error message? if not, can you capture it and edit it into your answer?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 Mate just landed out there - may be it makes sense to install fresher release?